# OpenERP and OpenSSO

Tags: python, saml, opensso, odoo

I need to make an OpenSSO authentication module for OpenERP, I'm currently checking the users_ldap module, and I want to check if this is the right way.

In this module there is reference to a service.security module and in this module there seems to be a check function.

So they do something like this:

security.check = ldap_check(security.check)

Ldap check seems to be the function that authenticates with LDAP.

Is this the right approach to write a module for OpenSSO.

Is there some way to redirect to the OpenSSO login, instead of using the OpenERP view?

Thanks a lot for your help!